# Boxplot and data outliers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot, data-science

I have data in a dictionary form that I convert to pandas that I am attempting to box plot data that is outside the range of 68 and 72. Ultimately I am trying to rotate the title of the box blot 90 degrees and also exclude outlier data if possible. In this snip below of my real world scenario its impossible to read to column header and its also not necessary to show the box plot if only a few outliers are outside the range 68 & 72. Any tips are greatly appreciated...

[image]

Ill make up some code that mimics my real world application.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[71.5,72.8,79.3],b=[70.2,73.3,74.9],c=[63.1,64.9,65.9],d=[70.1,70.9,70.9]))
```

Flag too hot:

```
TooHot = df.apply(lambda x: not (x > 72).any())
print('These zones are too warm')
df[TooHot[~TooHot].index].boxplot()
plt.show()
```

Flag too cool:

```
TooCool = df.apply(lambda x: not (x < 68).any())
print('These zones are too cool')
df[TooCool[~TooCool].index].boxplot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword arguments `showfliers=False` in `.boxplot()` will remove the outliers from displaying on the plot.
Using `vert=False` will make the boxplots horizontal (which I think is what you are asking?

The documentation on matplotlib boxplots is a good place to start: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html

Comment: Would you have any tips for incorporating excluding the outliers from my code with the `df.apply` above?

Comment: `df_toocool=df[df['Column']<68]` would give you a copy of the dataframe which only has the values from the `'Column'` column which are less than 68. You can then plot as you wish with that? Not sure exactly what your original question wants...

Comment: Im trying combine the data filtering into one statement to flag the data if its outside of the range of 68 or 72.. Any idea on how to do that? IE something like`df_OutOfRange=df[df['Column']<68, df['Column']>72]`

Comment: `df_OutOfRange=df[(df['Column']<68) & (df['Column']>72)]` would give the outliers.

Comment: I get an error with Python about 'Column'  -  # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality... Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about that error. But I have corrected my previous post as I should have used 'or' (`|`) instead of 'and' (`&`) as there is no situation when values are `<68 & >72` so the returned `df` would always be empty. It should read: `df_OutOfRange=df[(df['Column']<68) | (df['Column']>72)]`. This runs on the dataframe you gave in your example.

Comment: Im still getting this key error 'column'... Anyway I posted a new question on stack over flow, do you have time to look at it? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325049/pandas-iterate-over-dataframe-columns