# Pandas Iterate over dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

For my data in dictionary format to pandas, how do I flag datasets (column in my pandas dataframe) if any of the values are outside of the range of 68 & 72?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[71.5,72.8,79.3],
                       b=[70.2,73.3,74.9],
                       c=[63.1,64.9,65.9],
                       d=[70.1,70.4,70.9]))
```

What I am attempting to do is create a seperate pandas dataframe of column names if any data is outside of the range of 68 & 72. Any tips?

```
df_OutOfRange=df[(df.columns<68) | (df.columns>72)]

df_OutOfRange
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
In [48]: ((df < 68) | (df > 72)).any()
Out[48]:
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Or,

```
In [49]: (df.lt(68) | df.gt(72)).any()
Out[49]:
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Or,

```
In [62]: df.apply(lambda x: ~x.between(68, 72).all())
Out[62]:
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Details

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
      a     b     c     d
0  71.5  70.2  63.1  70.1
1  72.8  73.3  64.9  70.4
2  79.3  74.9  65.9  70.9
```